# how to get a bound or perplexity value of the new unseen document on trained model?

Tags: python, gensim

I would like to find outliers in my dataset by using LDA. In order to specify outliers, For this case, I am planning to use a bound or perplexity value of the new unseen document on trained model?
After that, I will sort the values in ascending order to check whether it is the outlier or not? 
My issue is that I could not get a bound/perplex value of individual doc, the model throws me **"TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable"** error.

I would appreciate if you help me to solve my case?

Just in case, I am attaching my code :

```
tokenized_corpora = dictionary.doc2bow(_acc[2])
total_number_of_words_tokenized_corpora = len(tokenized_corpora)
bound_corpora = ldaModel.bound(tokenized_corpora)
per_word_perplex_corpora = np.exp2(-bound_corpora / 
total_number_of_words_tokenized_corpora)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my research, in order to get log perplexity of single document, the following command can be used :

```
ldaModel.log_perplexity([bow])
```